# How to build CareKit sample apps

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, carekit

I want to investigate **Apple CareKit** by running the two included sample apps as mentioned in the ReadMe on GitHub: https://github.com/carekit-apple/CareKit

There are apparently two sample apps:

- [OCKCatalog](https://github.com/carekit-apple/CareKitCatalog)
- [OSKSample](https://github.com/carekit-apple/CareKitSample)

But when I look at the respective repositories, **no Xcode project files are included**, only the application files like AppDelegate, Info.plist etc.

I also tried to clone ResearchKit directly, again no sample app projects to be found.
Another approach was to create new Xcode projects from scratch and add the sample app files manually but I ran into unrelated version conflicts between CareKit and ResearchKit and other problems.

I simply want to play around with the sample apps, are we really supposed to set it all up ourselves?
Did the authors just forget to commit the Xcode project files?
Is there something I am missing here?